# How can I select only hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for some help with the mysql function `date_format`

```
SELECT * FROM bids 
WHERE bid_date = DATE_FORMAT('2014-07-13 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

I have tried the following

```
SELECT * FROM bids 
WHERE bid_date = DATE_FORMAT('00:00:00','%H:%i:%s')
```

but it didn't work

Comment: @devodedra it's mysql not mssql

Comment: select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM bid_date) from bids

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
%T Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)
```

Example:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%T')

Output: 11:45:34
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can just use HOUR:

```
  SELECT HOUR(Date) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

The EXTRACT() function is used to return a single part of a date/time, such as year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.

```
select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM bid_date) from bids
units:   
    MICROSECOND
    SECOND
    MINUTE
    HOUR
    DAY
    WEEK
    MONTH
    QUARTER
    YEAR
    SECOND_MICROSECOND
    MINUTE_MICROSECOND
    MINUTE_SECOND
    HOUR_MICROSECOND
    HOUR_SECOND
    HOUR_MINUTE
    DAY_MICROSECOND
    DAY_SECOND
    DAY_MINUTE
    DAY_HOUR
    YEAR_MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM bids WHERE DATE_FORMAT (bid_date,'%H:%i:%s') = DATE_FORMAT('00:00:00','%H:%i:%s')
```